# Работа с файлами Python. Как вывести только цифры?

Tags: python

Есть текстовый файл:

```
Name,55
Tttaa,43
Asdasdasd,222
Asdasdasd,203
Fdfsg,34
Gffdfd,64
Vxzczcv,55
Fdsafdf,99
Asdasd,231
```

Мне нужно из него вывести только числа в список, и после этого отсортировать. С сортировкой проблем нету, не могу только понять как внести только числа в список.

Делаю как-то так, но что-то не получается. Знаю, что можно readline использовать, но как именно записать числа в список?

```
group673=open("673.txt")
lst=group673.read().split(',')
print (lst)
group673.close()
```

Comment: приведите исходные данные в текстовом виде. и было бы не плохо показать свой код для начала.

Comment: если все строки в файле такого типа как на скрине, можно просто использовать `split(',')`

Comment: @whizz169 сплит по запятой разделит их парами, я бы сначала разделил по знаку перевода каретки '\n', а потом уже по запятой

Comment: используйте `re.findall`. Если сложно разбираться с регулярками, то регулярка для вашего случая будет выглядеть так `\d+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для работы с таблицами хорошо подходит модуль `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
rez = list(pd.read_csv('673.txt', header=None, names = ["text","digit"]).digit.values)
print (rez)        # [55, 43, 222, 203, 34, 64, 55, 99, 231]
```

можно и проще, но результатом будет не список, а массив:

```
import pandas as pd
rez = pd.read_csv('673.txt', header=None, names = ["text","digit"]).digit.values
print (rez)      # [ 55  43 222 203  34  64  55  99 231]
```

["text","digit"] - произвольно заданные имена столбцов.

если в исходный файл добавить в первую строку имена столбцов,

```
text,digit
Name,55     
Tttaa,43     
Asdasdasd,222      
Asdasdasd,203      
Fdfsg,34      
Gffdfd,64     
Vxzczcv,55     
Fdsafdf,99
Asdasd,231
```

то ответ такой:

```
import pandas as pd
rez = pd.read_csv('673.txt').digit.values
print (rez)      # [ 55  43 222 203  34  64  55  99 231]
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение через `re` будет выглядеть так

```
import re
with open("673.txt") as group673
    digits = re.findall(r'\d+', group673.read())
    print(digits)
# ['55', '43', '222', '203', '34', '64', '55', '99', '231', '90']
```

Если в списке нужны данные типа `int`, то можно записать так:

```
digits = [int(_) for _ in re.findall(r'\d+', group673.read())]
```

Или через `map`:

```
digits = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', group673.read())))
```

Или вообще упростить до

```
import re
digits = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', open('673.txt').read())))
```

Answer (score 1):

Например

```
with open("673.txt") as file:

    a = [line.strip().split(',')[1] for line in file]

print(a) # ['55', '43', '222', '515', '431', '222', '55', '437', '222']
```